# MVC 5 Getting the DisplayFormatAttribute of DbEntry

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a audit method that logs changes to my datatabase.

The method looks (abit)simplified like this

```
private List<Case_History> GetRecords(DbEntityEntry dbEntry, ApplicationUser user, int actionID)
{
    List<Case_History> result = new List<Case_History>();

    DateTime changeTime = DateTime.Now;

    // Finds the table
    TableAttribute tableAttr = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as TableAttribute;

    // Finds the table name
    string tableName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : dbEntry.Entity.GetType().BaseType.Name;

    // Finds primary key
    string keyName = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false).Count() > 0).Name;

else if (dbEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
{
    List<string> values = new List<string>();

    foreach (string propertyName in dbEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName), dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName)) && propertyName != "Modified_date")
        {
            //DEBUGGING VARIABLE
            var originalValue = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName);
            //DEBUGGING VARIABLE
            var newValue = dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName);

            //Here is the part where i want to get the column display name
            // This code is not working
            PropertyInfo prop = typeof(this).GetProperty(propertyName);
            var att = (DisplayAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute);
            if (att != null)
            {
                //found Display name
            }

            //If the record is different, record the change
            if (dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) != null && dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) != null)
            {
                    values.Add(propertyName + ": " + dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString() + " -> " + dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have found the variable in the locals in debugging session in the metadata propterties of the field. But only in the "this" variable. And this have to be dynamic for each different DBentries.

Comment: Why not replace typeof(this) to dbEntry.Entity.GetType()?

Comment: Ah oh wow. Yea it was that easy :) Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace

```
PropertyInfo prop = typeof(this).GetProperty(propertyName);
```

by

```
PropertyInfo prop = dbEntry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
```

Indeed, "this" is the current class, it contains no properties from the entity you want to log